# Custom Fluent Validation with combining NotEmpty() and When()

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

**Model - Product.cs**

```
public string id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public string type { get; set; }
public string status { get; set; }
```

**Fluent Validation Rule**

```
RuleFor(x => x.id).NotEmpty().When(x => x.status == "FIN").WithMessage("This field is required").IsValidInt();
RuleFor(x => x.name).NotEmpty().When(x => x.status == "FIN").WithMessage("This field is required");
RuleFor(x => x.type).NotEmpty().When(x => x.status == "FIN").When(x=>x.status == "FIN").WithMessage("This field is required").DDLIdExist();
```

Here *`IsValidInt()`* and *`DDLIdExist()`* are my custom validation rules. Also it only checks if the field non-empty when the status is set to **FIN**.

Now as you can see the part below is quite repetitive.

`NotEmpty().When(x => x.status == "FIN").WithMessage("This field is required")`

So my question is can I combine these two rules into a single custom validation function which takes `x.status` as an argument and prints "This field is required". If yes, how?

Comment: Yes, you can. RuleFor(x => x).BeSpokeRule();

Comment: I'm not sure how just writing a function name answers my question. Can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass the `AbstractValidator` class and define your custom rule to have more control.

```
public class ProductValidator : AbstractValidator<Product> {
  public ProductValidator() {
   RuleFor(x => x.Status).Custom((text, context) => {
     if(text == "FIN" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) {
       context.AddFailure("This field is required");
     }
   });
  }
}
```

Kindly note that this is just an idea, and not the actual way you'd go about doing this.

Refer to the docs [here](https://fluentvalidation.net/custom-validators)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap these calls in an extension method:

```
private static X RequiredWhenFIN(this Y y) => y.NotEmpty().When(x => x.status == "FIN").WithMessage("This field is required");
```

Where `Y` is the type returned by `RuleFor()` and `X` is the type returned by `WithMessage()`.

Then refactor your test like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.id).RequiredWhenFIN().IsValidInt();
RuleFor(x => x.name).RequiredWhenFIN();
RuleFor(x => x.type).RequiredWhenFIN().DDLIdExist();
```